# Customize emacs space indentation

Tags: emacs, indentation

I have to adjust to 4 space indentation for a project I'm collaborating on at work.  I hate looking at it, being accustomed to a nice compact 2 space indentation.  Is there any way to have emacs display 2 spaces as one? Or maybe tabify on file load, and untabify on save.  I'm working in c++.  I have searched through google, but can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: If you search Google for **tab-width emacs c-mode** you'll find a whole bunch of threads that already deal with this issue, some of which I have answered in the past.  You can modify those answers to apply to your specific major mode.  The current question is essentially a duplicate, but I don't have time at the moment to find an exact match -- in which case it would be a close vote as duplicative.

Comment: I don't have any issue setting the tab-width, it's in saving the file with 4 spaces, but viewing the file with them as 2 spaces.  I've perused all the Emacs indentation wikis, but can't seem to find what I want.  Maybe I'm  just dense :)

Comment: Ah ... I see now, thank you.  Then, how about?  `replace-regexp` (with `point-min` and `point-max` as the starting and ending points) when you start editing, and when you are all done a reverse `replace-regexp` -- have your regexp start from the left margin `^  ` and convert 4 to 2  when you begin and then 2 to 4 when you are done for the session of editing.  You can tighten up the regexp to avoid something you wish to exclude.  Type:  `M-x describe-function RET replace-regexp RET` to read more about that idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `prettify-symbols-mode`, which is built into Emacs >=24.5.

```
(defun jpk/contract-spaces ()
  (add-to-list 'prettify-symbols-alist '("  " . ?\ ))
  (prettify-symbols-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'jpk/c-contract-spaces)
```

This changes the display, not the content of the buffer or file.  I'm not sure this is the best idea.  It will affect (auto)indentation and you won't see what the saved file will look like.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try